# Getting value of an attribute within class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

i have a class method where i want to access the value of an attribute

```
class Run

  attr_accessor :line

  def self.output(options={})
    station_no = options[:station]
    title = options[:title]
    line = self.line
    station = line.stations[station_no-1]
  end
end
```

within this class method i want to access value of `line` attribute and within class method i can't access the value of an attribute using `self.line`. So please suggest me how i can access.

Answer (score 5):

Class method is executed in class context and `line` is instance method, you can't directly access it from `self.output`.

Do you really want to access instance attribute from class method? Maybe what you need is class attribute. If so, you can declare it like this:

```
class Run
  class << self
    attr_accessor :line
  end
end
```

, and will be able to get it's value within class method.

If you do need to access instance attribute from class method — pass that instance as argument to method and call accessor on it.

Comment: yeah i found out that i can't directly access attribute.. so how can i access `line` attribute within class method `self.output`?

Comment: +1 for "pass that instance as argument to method and call accessor on it". I think that is what he is looking at.